# Python metaclass behavior (not calling __new__), is there an explanation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

In a file named exp.py (below), I am trying to understand metaclasses in Python. It seems like when the metaclass's `__new__` method uses the 'type' constructor to construct a class, its `__new__` method does not get called by a subclass of a class using it as the metaclass:

```py
class A(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print "cls is:   ", cls
        print "name is:  ", name
        print "bases is: ", bases
        print "dct is:   ", dct
        print
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = A

class C(B): pass

class D(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print "cls is:   ", cls
        print "name is:  ", name
        print "bases is: ", bases
        print "dct is:   ", dct
        return type(name, bases, dct)

class E(object):
    __metaclass__ = D

class F(E): pass
```

In the terminal:

```
>>> from exp import *
cls is:    <class 'exp.A'>
name is:   B
bases is:  (<type 'object'>,)
dct is:    {'count': 0, '__module__': 'exp', '__metaclass__': <class 'exp.A'>, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x107eb9578>}

cls is:    <class 'exp.A'>
name is:   C
bases is:  (<class 'exp.B'>,)
dct is:    {'__module__': 'exp'}

cls is:    <class 'exp.D'>
name is:   E
bases is:  (<type 'object'>,)
dct is:    {'count': 0, '__module__': 'exp', '__metaclass__': <class 'exp.D'>, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x107ebdb18>}
>>>
```

As you can see, the `__new__` method of the metaclass D does not get called when class F's definition is loaded. (If it had been called, then information about the class F would have been printed too.)

Could someone help me explain this?

---

Related post: I was reading [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949), and seem to encounter something similar in the sentence, "Be careful here that the `__metaclass__` attribute will not be inherited, the metaclass of the parent (`Bar.__class__`) will be. If Bar used a `__metaclass__` attribute that created Bar with `type()` (and not `type.__new__()`), the subclasses will not inherit that behavior." But I did not fully understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case instead of returning an instance of the metaclass you're actually returning an instance of `type`, this in turn sets the `__class__` attribute of the newly created class `E` as `<type 'type'>` instead of `D`. Hence [as per the rule **2**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__) Python checks for base class's `__class__` attribute(or `type(E)` or `E.__class__`) and decides to use `type` as `F`'s metaclass, so `D`'s `__new__` is never called in this case.

- If `dict['__metaclass__']` exists, it is used.
- Otherwise, if **there is at least one base class, its metaclass is used** (this looks for a `__class__` attribute first and if not found, uses its type).

So, the proper way is to call type's `__new__` method in metaclass's `__new__` method:

```
class D(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print "cls is:   ", cls
        print "name is:  ", name
        print "bases is: ", bases
        print "dct is:   ", dct
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class E(object):
    __metaclass__ = D

class F(E): pass

class A(object):
    pass
```

**Output:**

```
cls is:    <class '__main__.D'>
name is:   E
bases is:  (<type 'object'>,)
dct is:    {'__module__': '__main__', '__metaclass__': <class '__main__.D'>}
cls is:    <class '__main__.D'>
name is:   F
bases is:  (<class '__main__.E'>,)
dct is:    {'__module__': '__main__'}
```

Comment: Great answer thank you! By the way, I have some questions on the phrase, "(this looks for a `__class__` attribute first and if not found, uses its type)." 1. In what type of situations would the `__class__` attribute be not found? 2. In what type of situations would the `__class__` attribute of a class be different from its type (as determined using `type()`)? Thank you

Comment: @platypus Old style classes don't have this attribute and even thier output for `type()` is different. For new-style classes default type is `type` and for old-style classes its `classobj`. [New-style and classic classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)